# converting a sql query to subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to determine the customers spending behavior by writing a query to select the top 10 highest spenders.

I have the following query and it works fine:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID
     , SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice) Total_Spent
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN OrderDetails d
    ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID 
  JOIN Customers c
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
 GROUP 
    BY c.CustomerID
 ORDER
    BY Total_Spent
 limit 10;
```

However, I want to create a subquery instead of having this complicated one. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID
FROM Customers
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(Quantity *UnitPrice) as Total_Spent
    FROM Orders
    JOIN OrderDetails
    ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID) Orders
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY Total_Spent
LIMIT 10;
```

I don't know what the problem is. (I am kinda new in SQL)

Comment: Your first query is the better way to go.  I would use table aliases, but there is no need for a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query because you don't need the `customers` table.  That and table aliases should make your query simpler:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) as Total_Spent
FROM Orders o JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
ORDER BY Total_Spent DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I need to use a subquery to generate the results. Is there any way to do that?